# How to modify a table so that CHECK TABLE fails in mysql 5.1?

Tags: mysql

I want to simulate an error for a table so that CHECK TABLE will fail.
Is there a way to simulate it so that CHECK TABLE on the table will fail ?

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING:** Before doing this, make sure you have a good backup, as you *will* lose data. Now is probably a good time to make sure you have `binlog` enabled and know how to do an point-in-time restore as well.

---

You can induce a corrupt table by shutting down MySQL, opening up the database file in an editor, changing/deleting a bunch of stuff, saving the file, then re-starting MySQL.

If you're using MyISAM tables, then just edit `/var/lib/mysql/<db_name>/<table_name>.MYD`. If you're using InnoDB and **don't** have `innodb_file_per_table` enabled, there's probably no easy way to do this. If you **do** have `innodb_file_per_table` enabled, then edit the `/var/lib/mysql/<db_name/<table_name>.ibd` file.

I just tested this with a MyISAM table:

```
mysql> check table watchdog;
+-------------------+-------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Table             | Op    | Msg_type | Msg_text                                              |
+-------------------+-------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| e_d7.watchdog     | check | error    | Size of datafile is: 151154         Should be: 162296 | 
| e_d7.watchdog     | check | error    | Corrupt                                               | 
+-------------------+-------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: ErikA, I have `innodb_file_per_table` enabled. I'll be doing this purely for InnoDB databases only. Let me try this out.

Comment: It seems that mysql wouldn't even start when I've modified the ibd file. Why would mysql crash because of one corrupted database (I have 10 other databases) ?